# TypeError: Cannot read property 'environment' of null

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 app that uses `@ionic-native/google-maps`. Getting the following stack trace:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'environment' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'environment' of null
    at Function.push../node_modules/@ionic-native/google-maps/index.js.Environment.setEnv (index.js:585)
    at TiedotPage.push../src/app/tiedot/tiedot.page.ts.TiedotPage.loadMap (tiedot.page.ts:41)
    at TiedotPage.<anonymous> (tiedot.page.ts:33)
    at step (tiedot.page.html:14)
    at Object.next (tiedot.page.html:14)
    at fulfilled (tiedot.page.html:14)
```

My code is here:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SijaintiService } from '../sijainti.service';
import { NavController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapOptions,
  CameraPosition,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker,
  Environment
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tiedot',
  templateUrl: './tiedot.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tiedot.page.scss'],
})
export class TiedotPage implements OnInit {

  info: any;
  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(public service: SijaintiService,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private platform: Platform) {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.map = this.service.getInfo();
    await this.platform.ready();
    await this.loadMap();
  }

  goBack() {
    this.navCtrl.back()
  }

  loadMap() {
    Environment.setEnv({
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE': 'MY_API_KEY',
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG': 'MY_API_KEY'
    })

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741904,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    }

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

    let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
      title: 'Ionic',
      icon: 'blue',
      animation: 'drop',
      position: {
        lat: 43.0741904,
        lng: -89.3809802
      }
    });
    marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
      alert('klikattu');
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I would put this into a Stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/) and make sure the error can be replicated.  Then someone can try and see if they can fix it.  What you have right now looks okay based on @ionic-native docs so more information is required - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is your exact issue, but.. What was the command you used on the CLI? You might need to target the environment variable on the CLI, such as this

```
ionic cordova build browser -l
```